# How do I switch two keyboard key actions?

Tags: mfc

I have a dialog-based MFC project. I have the `ON_WM_KEYDOWN()` function working and when I press the down key it does what it should.

Now I want to change the down key to the 'w' key, and the left key to 'a', etc. I have very basic MFC knowledge, I am not sure what function I should add and what part of the program to change.

My `ON_WM_KEYDOWN()` function looks as follows:

```
if(pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    switch(pMsg->wParam)
    {
    // Disable OK & Cancel function
    case VK_ESCAPE:
    case VK_RETURN:
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `pMsg->wParam` contains the key that has been pressed. You can look up the key codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As a result, you need some code similar to the following in your `ON_WM_KEYDOWN` handler:

```
if(pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    switch(pMsg->wParam)
    {
    case 0x57:
        // W key. Put code for "up" here...
        break;
    case 0x41:
        // A key. Put code for "left" here...
        break;
    case 0x53:
        // S key. Put code for "down" here...
        break;
    case 0x44:
        // D key. Put code for "right" here...
        break;
    // Disable OK & Cancel function
    case VK_ESCAPE:
    case VK_RETURN:
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

If you want the *A* key to perform the same action of the *cursor-left* key, for example, then you could do that by sending a `VK_LEFT` via a `WM_KEYDOWN` message with the [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9tdesxec.aspx) function:

```
PostMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LEFT, 0);
```

However, I didn't try this and I don't know if it's a good style to do so.

Comment: Thanks! So simple :)